# How can I set static ARP table for Arduino?

Tags: networking, arduino

I am working on a project which includes sending every keypad hit to udp server via UDP. But I'm stuck on problem that the first keypad hit works as dynamic ARP mapping, so I don't receive it on server. Is there any possibility to set static ARP table on Arduino?

I'm using UIPEthernet.h and Keypad.h libraries.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you may write a script and run during boot time which will set the your
static arp entry , if you have arp executable on your linux (may be through busybox) you can run following command :-

```
sudo arp -s <ipaddress> <mac>
```

exmaple:- sudo arp -s 10.0.0.2 00:0c:29:c0:94:bf

Comment: But that's on the server side. I meant how to set static arp of my server in arduino code. For example my server has 192.168.1.12 ip address and XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX mac address and I don't want arduino to send "who has 192.168.1.12" packet, but I want to set it manually in Arduino code.